# maximum number of partitions limit per table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am new to cassandra, As per my understanding depending on the configured partitioner(murmur3partitioner or randomaccess partitioner) there is a partitions  limit per table. if we configure keyspace with murmur3partitioner which would enforce the partitions limit of 2^63 partitions per table. while inserting the row, if the new insertion tries to create new partition beyond the limit, the insertion would fail(means if I get unique combinations of row keys more than 2^63 per table).

Can anyone please clarify, Is my understanding about partitions limit on column family is correct ?

And also as per my understanding there is no way to increase the partitions limit even by adding nodes into the cluster, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See also    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648479/choosing-a-partition-key-for-a-cassandra-table-how-many-is-too-many-partition

Answer (score 6):

The range of values for the murmur3 partitioner is actually  -2^63 to +2^63-1 That's a massive number. You aren't going to run out of values in any practical sense. No worries.

Comment: Yep, that should be good for 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible values.

Comment: Why you used murmur3 partitioner when question asked for Cassandra partition ?
if its for Cassandra partition only does it valid for all versions of Cassandra such as Cassandra 2.x , 3.X, 4.X